# Real time data from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Am I able to push real time data from google analytics to google spreadsheet via google analytics add-on? (I know that it is possible via Google Analytics API)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty hard to prove a negative but no, you cannot do this from within the interface, you'd need the [Google Analytics Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/).

I am not convinced that this is really useful. Realtime data is not aggregated, so you'd get a lot of rows really fast (and since a [Google spreadsheet holds 2 mio cells at most](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en) you'd have to empty or swap the spreadsheet regularly).

Since this is basically raw data you could just as well set up a [small apps script like in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293) that writes request data to a spreadsheet, publish this as web app and create a small image pixel within your page that sends data directly to the sheet (but you will not have channel attribution). [I expanded a bit on that idea here](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/pagecounter-with-ga-spreadsheets/).